# weird behavior of module require in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

It's hard to explain so I will reproduce the code.

I have two class files.

**Business.js**

```
const Street = require("./Street");

module.exports = class Business {};
```

**Street.js**

```
const Business = require("./Business");

module.exports = class Street {
  constructor() {
    console.log(Business);
  }
};
```

and index.js file

```
const Street = require("./Street");

const street = new Street();
```

when I run **index.js** (node ./index.js), it log `[Function: Business]` as expect,

but when I require `Business.js` in index.js file like below, log message change, it log empty object `{}`.

**index.js**

```
const Business = require("./Business");
const Street = require("./Street");

const street = new Street();
```

I don't understand why require Business in index.js effect log message in **Street.js** file.

try it out codesandbox.

[image: Edit node module misbehavior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is a circular dependency. Ideally a module should not depend on a module that depend on that module.

Since your Business.js module depend on Street.js module and Street.js module depend on Business.js module (which is called a circular dependency) you are getting this "weird behavior".

Any restructure that avoid circular dependency will be okay, like moving both classes to the same file (just a suggestion, you may want to use another way as your use case and coding practices).

```
class Street {
  constructor() {
    console.log(Business);
  }
}

class Business {}

module.exports = {
  Street,
  Business
};
```

try it out codesandbox.

[image: Edit node module misbehavior]

Comment: thanks now I know the term (circular dependency), I can google it, anyway my use case is Street and Business is a model with relation that mean they depend on each other, how can I avoid circular dependency, any link of article is appreciate